# Getting attribute value of an element from its specific sub-element

Tags: android, xml, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to use xmlstarlet on my Mac to get the attribute value of an element from its sub-element, here is an example

I have an  xml file with a lot of elements like this, the attributes like android:configChanges vary from element to element:

```
<activity android:configChanges="ABC" android:screenOrientation="XXX">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="XYZ"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the thing is that the value of `category android:name` is unique to this element which is `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Is there a way using xmllint or xmlstarlet where i run the

```
xmlstarlet <magic code> <filename>
```

the `<magic code>` should be able to tell the value of `android:configChanges` and `android:screenOrientation` when it is provided that `/activity/intent-filter/category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`

thus, the deisred output should be

```
android:configChanges="ABC" android screenOrientation="XXX"
```

so far the only thing i know is how to get the value of other sub-elements from a specific sub-element using

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/activity/intent-filter/category[@android:name=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]/*" file.xml
```

which returns

```
<action android:name="XYZ"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

Any help will be appriciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Shell Script to help me do this :)

```
b="$(grep -n "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" File.xml | cut -f1 -d:)"
head -n $b File.xml >/tmp/foo.txt
f="$(awk '/activity/{k=$0}END{print k}' /tmp/foo.txt)"
echo $f >> /tmp/file.xml
echo "</activity>" >> /tmp/file.xml
sed -i -e 's/android:/d/g' /tmp/file.xml
xmllint --xpath "string(//activity/@dconfigChanges)" /tmp/file.xml
xmllint --xpath "string(//activity/@dscreenOrientation)" /tmp/file.xml
```

Since i am using a unix based operating system and not limited to using only xmlstarlet, i made a script that `greps` the value "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" and then uses `head` from that file appending all the lines above "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" to a new text file. to find the first instance of `<activity`, the script then uses grep and tail to search from the bottom of the new text file. this returns the full value of `<activity android:configChanges="ABC" android:screenOrientation="XXX">` as a string, using `echo` and `>>` the string is output as an xml file. since the string doesnt contain a `</activity>` the script `echo`'s `<activity>` into the file. `sed` is used to replace the `android:` in each attribute with `d` because `:` cant be used. using `xmllint` we can then find the value of the attributes `android:configChanges` and `android:screenOrientation` easily.

Output:

```
ABC
XXX
```

as expected

**Edit:**

Changed `f="$(grep "<activity" /tmp/foo.txt | tail -$b)"` to `f="$(awk '/activity/{k=$0}END{print k}' /tmp/foo.txt)"` the awk command gets the last occurence of `activity` in the foo.txt file, it works becuase of the `head -n $b File.xml >/tmp/foo.txt` command before, which only takes the first `b` lines of the file